# What is this key, and where is it on a MacBook Air?

Tags: keyboard

This is a picture of a tooltip from IntelliJ IDEA. Does anyone know what key is being referred to? I don't have anything like it on my MacBook Air.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the symbol used for the escape key (<kbd>esc</kbd>), located on the upper left corner of pretty much any keyboard, MacBook Air included.